# Why does SICK LMS200 not work with angle = 180 and resolution = 0.25

Tags: ros, sicklms, resolution

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have been trying to perform some laser scanning using LMS200. I am using the sicktoolbox wrapper and setting

```
rosparam set sicklms/angle 180
rosparam set sicklms/resolution 0.25
```

But everytime it throws me a warning saying "Unable to set resolution. Using 5.000000e-01 instead of 2.500000e-01" and finally settles with resolution 1.0. However, if I give the combination as (100,0.25) instead of (180,0.25), it works fine and I get the desired resolution. Can anyone throw any light on this strange behavior?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187597/why-does-sick-lms200-not-work-with-angle-=-180-and-resolution-=-0.25/) by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the SICK cannot do it's highest resolution at full width of range. It is bandwidth limited in the amount of samples it can take and report.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2015-01-02**:
Yup, see Table 5-1 on page 11 of the [manual](http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/docs/sick-lms-technical-description.pdf). Its max scanning angle is limited to 100 degrees when using an angular resolution of 0.25 degrees.